# PHP - Is fstat() cached?

Tags: php, caching, documentation

I'd like to know if [fstat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat) is cached.

Documentation says nothing about it.

(PHP 8.1.12)

**EDIT:**

I made a LOT of tests, I have now an accurate answer for that.

**Introduction:**

I created two scripts and ran them both simultaneously (locking the file pointer with an exclusive lock ([flock($fp, LOCK_EX)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock))* to prevent them from overwriting each other) and on their own; I printed [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r)([fstat($fp)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat)) at various stages of a loop that led to writing 5 MB of data. I also used [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump)([realpath_cache_get()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-get.php))

> Returns an array of realpath cache entries. The keys are original path entries, and the values are arrays of data items, containing the resolved path, expiration date, and other options kept in the cache.

to detect the realpath cache and ran tests trying to clear and not clear the cache via [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

**What happened:**

I found that the only item that gets cached is 'atime'

> time of last access (Unix timestamp)

But most upsetting of all: it is not put in the realpath cache, consequently nothing will change if you clear it via [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), you can only restart the machine or wait for the cache timeout to clear the data (depending on the machine).

Fortunately this doesn't affect me since I only need 'size' element of fstat. Sadly I cannot give you the source code cause I changed it a lot of time to try all possibilities.

Thank you to everyone who spent time to help me.

*NOTE: Use flock in both files, if you use it only in one the other file will be able to write in the not locked file that has been ran before

**CONCLUSION**

The only cached element of [fstat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock) is atime, but it is not cached in the [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-get.php), so [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) is useless

Comment: If it doesn't say, then you can't count on it. You could check the source code.

Comment: Looking at [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/71078de71ae2ee1da099b6efb9c88952651f0390), I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1031

Comment: A lot of different answers, a little bit confused

Comment: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/php/2003/function.fstat.html

Comment: ✅ Agree with @ChrisHaas

Comment: @MohammedJhosawa, I'm getting even more confused the deeper I get: https://github.com/php/doc-en/commit/121447cca4a1224959b4537577431ca309bbc0fb

Comment: Same here @ChrisHaas

Comment: I did a test. Create a file, fopen , fstat, sleep(2), read file, fstat again, both results compared.
Win10 returned a difference in 'atime' , Linux did not. I think it depends on the OS, less on PHP.

Comment: @jspit, I agree, and it might also depend on the underlying stream type, too

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick demo that *appears* to show that it is *not* cached. However, **see the edit,** too

```php
$filename = __DIR__.'/test.txt';

@unlink($filename);
touch($filename);
echo 'STAT - Size before write: '.stat($filename)['size'], PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filename, 'test');
echo 'STAT - Size after write: '.stat($filename)['size'], PHP_EOL;
clearstatcache();
echo 'STAT - Size after cache clear: '.stat($filename)['size'], PHP_EOL;

@unlink($filename);
touch($filename);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
echo 'FSTAT - Size before write: '.fstat($fp)['size'], PHP_EOL;
fwrite($fp, 'test');
echo 'FSTAT - Size after write: '.fstat($fp)['size'], PHP_EOL;
clearstatcache();
echo 'FSTAT - Size after cache clear: '.fstat($fp)['size'], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
STAT - Size before write: 0
STAT - Size after write: 0
STAT - Size after cache clear: 4
FSTAT - Size before write: 0
FSTAT - Size after write: 4
FSTAT - Size after cache clear: 4
```

**Edit**

Per @Barmar, I ran the test again, this time with just an `fstat` call followed by a sleep(10), then I quickly updated the file with vim manually, and then one final `fstat` call (all in the same request), and that one came back as *cached*.

I then ran that again, this time with `clearstatcache()` before the final `fstat`, and it did not change. I also tried the tests with both `w` and `r` modes for `fopen`, same results.

So there does appear to be a cache of some sort, but I don't think it is the stat cache.

Comment: I expect that performing an operation on the stream would clear the cache automatically. You need to do the write from a different process to see if this process maintains the cache.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I was trying to compare it to the `stat` one which is where I see most people run into trouble because local FS changes aren't always apparent. But I just performed a test with a `sleep`, wrote to the file with vim quickly, and then checked stat, and that is showing it as cached.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement:

I also did exactly such a test as Chris Haas describes in the comment.

```
/*
 * Open test.txt with a text editor
 * Run this script
 * Add some characters in the editor and save while the script is running
 */
$file = __DIR__.'/../test/test.txt';
$fp = fopen($file,'r');
$size[] = fstat($fp)['size'];
sleep(10);
$size[] = fstat($fp)['size'];
var_dump($size);
//array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(13) }
```

Same results for PHP on Win10 and a small Linux.

Comment: So to be clear, your version is showing as not cached?